# KnockoutJS remove binding on selected element by class

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

I have simple menu (dynamically generated) which part of it looks like

```
<span class="shared-folder icon-down-mini e-collapsed-sign" data-bind="css: collapsedCss()">
    <span class="name shared-folder" data-bind="text: name">shared-email@mydomain.com</span>
</span>
<span class="shared-folder icon-none e-collapsed-sign" data-bind="css: collapsedCss()">
     <span class="name" data-bind="text: name">INBOX</span>
</span>
```

Then I have tried to remove binding via `ko.cleanNode` for an element which has a class `icon-none`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.cleanNode($(".icon-none")[0]);           
</script>
```

But that is not working - is still triggering `collapsedCSS()` binding on INBOX.

Code for `collapsedCSS` looks like:

```
    FolderModel.prototype.collapsedCss = function ()
    {
        return this.hasSubScribedSubfolders() ?
            (this.collapsed() ? 'icon-right-mini e-collapsed-sign' : 'icon-down-mini e-collapsed-sign') : 'icon-none e-collapsed-sign';
    };
```

Probably bindings in RainLoop:

`this.collapsed = ko.observable(true);` from `AbstractModel.call(this, 'FolderModel');`

and then

```
        this.collapsed = ko.computed({
            'read': function () {
                return !this.hidden() && this.collapsedPrivate();
            },
            'write': function (mValue) {
                this.collapsedPrivate(mValue);
            },
            'owner': this
        });
```

Any clue why is not working or it will be better to use jQuery and remove `data-bind` attribute on an element with `icon-none` class?

Comment: Can you post how you are applying your bindings?

Comment: That part is done by RainLoop code

Comment: @NickDeFazio What exactly do I need to look for? I will do grep through the RainLoop code

Comment: My initial thought was that you were applying bindings to a higher scope, (via ko.applyBindings) then trying to clean a node within that bound scope, and wasn't sure that would work correctly. Though I just tried that in a fiddle and it seems okay.

Comment: I have done a test on a fiddle and was working but not when I have applied to RainLoop template :\

Comment: @NickDeFazio I have update OP probably with bindings from RainLoop